# website opened only once on a browser

Tags: browser, tabs

I would like to have a website opened only once on a browser. I want to force somehow to have only one tab opened. What solutions do I have?

I need to make it work on any browser.

Comment: Why do you have this requirement? In general that is not how browsers work and/or users of browsers expect websites to work...

Comment: In short, This is not **possible**

Comment: Do you have a session?

Answer (score 0):

You may find a way using a request counter in a session cookie. In every server response the counter is sent back incremented. Per JS you can compare cookie and counter. Should there be a difference of more than one some other tab is sending requests as well. Obviously, you may encounter race conditions.

Comment: Problem here is, that any newly opened tab will take over and the old one is the one that shows the message that only one tab can be used. It would recognize this after a request or with a intervalled JS that compares the cookie to the request counter (the cookie will have out-grown the counter)